# Access query for deleting repeats in next months

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have problem writing Access sql query. I want to select rows with id for each months with no repeats in later months, if id appears in january and february, it should be omitted in february etc.
Of course I have data for whole year. 
Example data

```
Month   id
__________
01-15   1
01-15   2
01-15   3
01-15   5
01-15   2
02-15   1
02-15   4
02-15   4
02-15   5
03-15   1
03-15   9
```

Result should be

```
01-15   1
01-15   2
01-15   3
01-15   5
01-15   2
02-15   4
02-15   4
03-15   9
```

So far i make vba macro for it with loop

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim list As String, sql As String, okres As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 12 Step 1
    If i < 10 Then
        okres = "0" & i
    Else
        okres = i
    End If

   sql = "SELECT DISTINCT [ID] INTO SRC from [TMP] where okres = '" & okres & "-15';"
   db.Execute sql, dbFailOnError
   sql = "DELETE [TMP].* FROM [TMP] WHERE [ID] in (SELECT * from SRC) and okres <> '" & okres & "-15';"
   db.Execute sql, dbFailOnError
   sql = "DROP TABLE SRC"
   db.Execute sql, dbFailOnError
Next i
```

It runs fine, but i want write it in one sql query.

Comment: Is your month really stored in that awful format?  You should always store dates as YYYY-MM-DD (or in this case YYYY-MM), so you can do appropriate comparisons.

Comment: I know that, however i get this data from someone else, and there is no chance to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `exists` subquery to find rows that repeat earlier rows:

```
DELETE  yt1
FROM    YourTable yt1
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    YourTable yt2
        WHERE   yt1.ID = yt2.ID AND
                    mid(yt2.TheMonth, 3, 2) + mid(yt2.TheMonth, 1, 2) <
                    mid(yt1.TheMonth, 3, 2) + mid(yt1.TheMonth, 1, 2)
        )
```

The `where` condition looks for:

- A row with the same ID
- An earlier date.  The dates are converted from `MM-YY` to `YYMM` so they can be compared.

Comment: I cant belive how stupid I am,  i was thinking about EXCEPT, but i forget that i can use > operator. Thanks for advice, it works great.